# Can anyone calculate the area of the top shape in this diagram?

Tags: geometry, area

http://postimg.org/image/w5f5moq7z/

The top shape on the diagram is the sensor that I need to calculate the area for. I have tried using the 2 elipses at the side and combining them together to get a full elipse but I'm not sure how accurate that is

Comment: To me it looks like a rectangle with [circle segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) at the left and right. That makes sense, circles are much easier to manufacture than ellipses. But without more precise dimensions all you'll get is a (more or less) crude approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have a circle with radius $2.0975$ with part of the circle removed top and bottom(radius here 1.775).

$4\int_0^{1.775} \int_0^{\sqrt{(2.0975)^2 - y^2}} 1 \;\mathrm{d}x \; \mathrm{d}y$,  Or you can you alternative coordinates. Note: I haven't used $\pm$ here, but I am sure you can work out the method(assuming some calculus has been obtained).

Note: The above text tells us that it was a circle with top and bottom removed. Hence the basis of my method.

Above evaluates to $4*3.21114 = 12.8446$(unit)$^2$, and this is your answer.

Below we have the entire region plotted, and under it the integral of the region in totality, below that we have my first method(I broke the region into four parts and integrated it, and multiplied by four), with it's integral underneath it. Note these integrals evaluate to be one and the same.

[image]

Comment: I need to head out for 2hrs to take my son to nursery. Once I come back I'm cracking this. Spent 2 days on it before I decided to ask for some hints. All help so far has been much appreciated

Comment: Is this correct?    You're given the dimensions to make 2 sides of a triangle describing half of the inside of each curved section 3.55 /2 = 1.775 by 0.7975. This gives you your opp and adj side so inv. tan to get the angle.

Comment: The radius line can be found by subtracting this angle from 90 and then a second triangle made using this angle (90 - theta) and the original adj 1.775. use the cosine to find a value for the hyponteneuse - this is the radius of your circle - it's also worth finding the angle formed at the centre of the circle at this point ( easily done once you have (90- theta) and a right angle. By doubling this angle you have the angular arc described and the radius from which you can easily calculate the area of the arc (pi r squared/ (angle/360))

Comment: subtract from this the triangular area covered using 0.5xbasexheight and you have the area of one of your curved sections. multiply by 2 to include the other and then add in the area of the sqare (or rectangular middle section and you're done).

Comment: @user158164 Refer to edit please.

Comment: @user158164 Have you already handed in solution(rendering this irrelevant)? When you find out the answer, could you let me know if I was correct please?

Answer (score 1):

The centre square is, assuming Max area, 2.54mm by 3.55mm giving an area of: 9.017mm

Each segment has a base (h) of 3.55mm and a height (c):of 1.01mm.

Using this information we can calculate the radius (R) of the circle that the sectors would be a part of:
R=h/2 + c²/8h 
R=1.902

The angle (a, rad) that forms the sector is given by:
a = 2arcsin(c/2R)

Giving the nice result that is almost pi radians.

Area is found by then using the information gathered thus:

A = (R²/2)(a - sin(a)) = 5.67mm (Max area)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 0.25 is not applicable here as I think that's the limit of error that was to be used in a previous question. Also the centre isnt square. This is what's causing me the problem. The centre is 3.5x 2.54

Comment: @user158164 correct, i mis-wrote, as i also asserted the measurements of a rectangle!